# Refreshing Angular view after changing a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Because the page I am working on is a legacy page with lots of dead/living/zombie code I am unable to paste it whole here. So I am trying to post a digest of my issue with sample code.

I have a page in which data comes from Angular. It is a bunch of products. Each product has an attribute named `showProduct` that determines it should be shown or not. The `showProduct` attribute is set to `1` when it is first fetched from the backend. While rendering the html, in each product div I have
`ng-show={{product.showProduct}}`. The `ng-show` works correctly the first time when its loaded, all products are shown. If from the backend I set this to 0 for any product, it is hidden.

Once the products are loaded, if the user clicks a button, I need to hide some of those products. This button click handler is in jQuery.

So I do the following:

```
  prod =  angular.element($('#product-section')).scope().ProductList;
```

`prod` is now an array of products with their attributes. Now I iterate through this array, check for the attribute in question (which I know based on what button was clicked) and based on its value for each product, I set a `showProduct` attribute to `0`.

However this does not update the view, to hide that product. If I `console.log` the `angular.element($('#product-section')).scope().ProductList`, I can see that its showProduct has correctly been update from 1 to 0.

I am assuming that there is something I need to do in order to make the productList be "re-parsed" and refreshed in the page. However I am not sure how to do this.

I just needed some conceptual tips on what I might be missing, because I understand that providing "specific" code tip for my situation is difficult.

In a nutshell, once I have updated the angular value externally, how do I tell Angular to reparse the code and refresh the view? Something like how it happens automatically for models when updating data in a textbox...

I tried doing `angular.element($('#product-section')).scope().$apply();` but that did not work.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    angular.element($('#product-section')).scope().ProductList;
});
```

By doing this, you're telling AngularJS to watch what your enclosed code is doing and update the view accordingly.

Just some consideration: wouldn't you be able to just update the model directly instead of invoking an external code? This approach is always recommended.

Comment: Just a notice: `$scope.$apply could` could be problematic, when used on it's own (there could be a digest cycle running already.). You could use `$timeout(callback-func, 0)` to work around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses two way data binding, which works, when you use an Angular-Controller (or Directive, etc), in which you define your model. In your HTTML you use something like this (very crude example):

```
<div ng-controller="myProductListController>"
    <div ng-repeat="(index, product) in productList">
        <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`productList`is in your `myProductListController` and is available in the scope (your model) of your `ng-controller` directive.

Now, each time the `productList` changes in your controller, your view will update automatically.

Scopes (models) are bound to some Angular-Controller (or Directive, ...). So you need to have that, in order to use two-way-binding here.

Hope that helps